# Filter values at ListBox from TextBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have one problem that I think is easy to solve but for someone reason I didn't find it. I find lot of examples at web but for some reason didn't work (show the values only one column...)

I have a Userform with a Multiplage with two pages and I want to show at Listbox2 on the second page the values match value TextBox2 with Column B at the Sheet.

I want that when you navigate trough records at page 1 If you select page 2 show at Listbox2 the 6 columns from sheet (C:H) but only for these who TextBox2 value match with Column B at the sheet.

This code works if I didn't include the filter lines, but show me all the data stored and If I include the filter line at codes it show me anything.

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
If Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1 Then ' If you select second page show at listBox2 the values match with TextBox2
      rng = Sheets("Page1").Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Resize(, 8).Value
   With ListBox2
    .List = rng
    .ColumnCount = UBound(rng, 2)
    For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1 ' If I delete code form hereListbox2 show all the values, if maintain it show me anything
     If .List(i, X) <> TextBox2.Value Then .RemoveItem (i)
    Next
  End With
End If
End Sub
```

I hope you have any suggestion, it will be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want values that are partially matching. What you do is filter based on exact match. So, I think that could work for you:

```
If Not .List(i, X) Like "*" & TextBox2.Value & "*" Then .RemoveItem (i)
```

or

```
If Not TextBox2.Value Like "*" & .List(i, X) & "*" Then .RemoveItem (i)
```

Since you provided very little details, it's only a guess.

Also, if that doesn't do the job, I still think that `Like` operator could solve your problem and you should consider using it -> [Reference article](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) :)